# Perl XML::LibXML textContent

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

Is there any way how to keep tags of nodes from xml code? Explanation of the problem could be like this: I have an xml input, I query the input and I want to get xml output of the queried items.

```
<pets>
  <dog>
    <name>Maggie</name>
    <dob>12 October 2005</dob>
    <price>75</price>
    <owner>Rosie</owner>
  </dog>
</pets>
```

When I access `//pets/dog` in my Perl program, the output is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<dog>
    Maggie
    12 October 2005
    75
    Rosie
</dog>
```

Is there any way to give the function `textContent` some parameter
to keep the tags? This is a block of my cycle code that puts the nodes
into hash, then outputs it:

```
$parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$data = $parser->load_xml(string => $takeninput);
$xml = new XML::LibXML::XPathContext($data);
$i = 0;
for $node ($xml->findnodes('//pets/dog'))
  {
    $name = $node->nodeName;
    $hash{$name}[$i] = $node->textContent;
    $i++;
  }
```

To *keep the tags* of children? To have the output like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<dog>
    <name>Maggie</name>
    <dob>12 October 2005</dob>
    <price>75</price>
    <owner>Rosie</owner>
</dog>
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is doing exactly what you asked - it is returning the text content of the node. Markup isn't text content so it doesn't give it to you.

What I think you want is `$node->toString`, which will return the `dog` node as formatted XML.

For a pretty layout, use `$node->toString(1)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was the whole day looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::XSH2;

xsh << '__XSH__';
    open 1.xml ;
    ls //pets/dog |> $x ;
__XSH__

print $XML::XSH2::Map::x;
```

Output:

```
<dog>
    <name>Maggie</name>
    <dob>12 October 2005</dob>
    <price>75</price>
    <owner>Rosie</owner>
  </dog>
```